# swf to jpg using actionscript

Tags: flash

Is it possible to convert an swf to image using actionscript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You question needs a bit more detail. So I will make some assumptions.

I assume that you want to take a snapshot of the current state of you SWF, and then save that as an image file. You don't tell us where you want to save the image e.g. on a server, on the users local machine, or even keep it inside flash etc. so I can't really help you much there.

It is quite easy to get a snapshot of your SWF. What you want is the BitmapData class. This function should help. Just pass it a reference to a DisplayObject (can be stage), and it will return you the BitmapData object.

```
function snapClip(clip:DisplayObject):BitmapData
{
    var bmpData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(stage.width, stage.height, true, 0);
    bmpData.draw( clip, new Matrix() );
    return bmpData;
}

var bmpData:BitmapData = snapClip( stage );
```

From there you can add the BitmapData to the stage like this:

```
var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
mc.addChild( new Bitmap(bmpData) );
addChild(mc);
```

Or you can encoder your BitmapData into JPEG format:

```
import com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder;
var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(85);
var jpgStream:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(bmpData);
```

From here, to save it to a server you need to send the byteArray to a server-side script that can handle the saving.

Here are some links that may help:

- [Taking a MovieClip Snapshot](http://jobemakar.blogspot.com/2007/05/taking-movieclip-snapshot.html)
- [How to draw anything into a BitmapData properly](http://www.quasimondo.com/archives/000670.php)
- [Using the AS3 Jpeg Encoder](http://henryjones.us/articles/using-the-as3-jpeg-encoder)
- [Upload BitmapData Snapshot to Server in AS3](http://www.quietless.com/kitchen/upload-bitmapdata-snapshot-to-server-in-as3/)

Comment: I have a swf and when i click on a button it must get converted into jpg and saved as an image...

I have no idea on flash, i need an example... can u show it.

Comment: That last link I gave comes with "Source Example Files" to download.